# MySQL - Last 6 months excluding the current week

Tags: mysql

I'm on a MySQL database and I want to extract the last 6 excluding the last current week.

Example: Today is week 11.
So I want to have the dates for the last 6 months up to week 10.

I have this SQL query, it pulls the last 6 months fine but it takes the last week.

```
select *
from table
where date_table BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND CURDATE();
```

Comment: Add an `AND` in the `WHERE` clause specifying that the date can't be during the current week. You can do it with a very similar statement to what you have, including a `NOT`.

Comment: What is "last 6 month"? 6 months interval substracting may adjust day-in-month number. *but it takes the last week* - substract day-of-week days from current date..